# Malloc with struct

Tags: c, malloc, ram, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is the code in C, compiled on Ubuntu 15.10:

-----  node_tree.h -----

```
    struct node_tree{ 
        int key;
        char value[20];
        struct node_tree* right_child;
        struct node_tree* left_child;
    };
    typedef struct node_tree* node;
```

----- tree_test_main.c -----

```
    #include "node_tree.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <assert.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <time.h>

    int main(){
        //root
        node root = malloc(sizeof(node));
        root->key = 1;
        strcpy(root->value, "Ciao");

        //left child
        node left = malloc(sizeof(node));
        left->key = 2;
        strcpy(left->value, "Maremma");

        //right child
        node right = malloc(sizeof(node));
        right->key = 3;
        strcpy(right->value, "Maiala");

        root->left_child = left;
        root->right_child = right;

        printf("%d, %s\n", root->key, root->value);
        printf("%d, %s\n", root->left_child->key, root->left_child->value);
        printf("%d, %s\n", root->right_child->key, root->right_child->value);

        free(root);
        free(right);
        free(left);
    }
```

This is the console output, I can't understand why the string '8446000' appears.
I tried the same code on Mac OS X and it works fine.

```
1, Ciao
8446000, 
3, Maiala
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x000000000080e010 ***
[1]    3926 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

Comment: And this, sir, is why I usually avoid that kind of `typedef`. You have to *type* less, but tend to forget what the *actual* type of the thing is.

Comment: To clarify that comment, please note that whether or not to use `typedef` together with `struct` is entirely a style matter. Most C programmers use `typedef struct`, except Linux programmers who prefer not to. Neither style is wrong. However, _hiding a pointer behind a typedef_ is not a style matter, but simply bad and dangerous programming practice.

Answer (score 3):

```
    node root = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

This allocates size for the pointer, not the structure. Try this:

```
    node root = malloc(sizeof(*root));
```

Similarly for other variables.

Comment: `node` is a type name and `*node` will emit compile error.

Comment: @MikeCAT I meant `root`

Answer (score 2):

`node` is a pointer type and its size will be less than size of the struct, so there are insufficient space allocated and you are accessing out-of-range.

Try using `sizeof(struct node_tree)` instead of `sizeof(node)`.

I suggest you should stop using `typedef` to the pointer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the reasons you should not hide pointers behind typedef.

`sizeof(node)` returns `sizeof(struct node_tree*)`, not `sizeof(struct node_tree)` as you expect.

Change the typedef to *not* hide the pointer:

```
typedef struct node_tree node;
```

And to be safe, allocate using variable rather than type:

```
node * root = malloc(sizeof(*root));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate the right size:

```
node N = malloc(sizeof *N);
```

Try to print their size to see it:

```
printf("sizeof N =  %zu", sizeof N);
printf("sizeof *N = %zu", sizeof *N);
```

EDIT: replaced type with variable.

Comment: `node` is a type name and `*node` will emit compile error.